# How can I move the most recent few commits to my git repo to their own branch off a specific historical commit?

Tags: git

I have this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G  (master branch)
```

Where F and G are my recent commits and E is the last commit from the origin.

What I need is to make F and G into a separate branch, which other questions cover, but based on commit B, leaving this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E  (master branch)
      \
       F -- G  (my new branch)
```

The reason is that commit B is tagged as the stable release (in use on other systems not maintained using git) and I need to make a patch file of commits F and G against that release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout B
git branch my_new_branch
git checkout my_new_branch
git cherry-pick F
git cherry-pick G
```

But this creates only

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G  (master branch)
      \
       F -- G  (my new branch)
```

now you need reset master history:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^^
```

this will make

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E  (master branch)
      \
       F -- G  (my new branch)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout B

git branch my_new_branch

git checkout my_new_branch
```

That creates a new `my_new_branch` on `B`. Then you need to:

```
git cherry-pick F

git cherry-pick G
```

**Note that `[A-G]` are the commits hash numbers**

Comment: in this case F and G would be left in master branch too